# Routing redirect To other link in Angular problem

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

Oke, I try to get the adviceRouterModule working.

Of course I tried a lot. googled. But I can't figure it out.

So I have this AdviceRoutingModule:

```
const adviceRouters: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AdviceNavigationComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {path: '', redirectTo: 'huidig', pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
      {path: 'huidig', component: AdviceComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
      {path: 'archief', component: AdviceArchiveComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    ]
  }
];


@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(adviceRouters)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})



export class AdviceRoutingModule {}
```

and the advicenavigation template looks like this:

```
<nav class="nav-tab-bar">
  <a routerLink="/advies/huidig" routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-tab-bar-tab">Adviezen</a>
  <a routerLink="/advies/archief" routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-tab-bar-tab">Eerdere Adviezen</a>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

So the working example has to if a user klicks on Adviezen, the user has to be directed to:

```
http://localhost:4200/advies/huidig
```

But nothing happens now

That the url works correct.

I have it now like this:

```
const adviceRouters: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'advies',
    component: AdviceNavigationComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {path: '', redirectTo: 'huidig', pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
      {path: 'huidig', component: AdviceComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
      {path: 'archief', component: AdviceArchiveComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    ]
  }
];
```

and of course in the advice.moduel:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [

       AdviceRoutingModule,
        CommonModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        SharedModule
       ],
```

ahhh, this was the trick:

```
const adviceRouters: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'advies',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {path: '', redirectTo: 'huidig', pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
      {path: 'huidig', component: AdviceComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
      {path: 'archief', component: AdviceArchiveComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: What do I wrong? I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add 'advies' to the "main" path i think, like this :

const adviceRouters: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'advies'
    ...

Comment: Also do not forget to import the `AdviceRoutingModule` in the `AdviceModule`

Comment: Oke, But now I see double navigation links: